# Is the local variable returned by a function automatically moved in C++20?

Tags: c++, return-value, c++20

Please consider a C++ program, where the function `foo` builds its returning `U` object from a local variable of type `int` using one of two constructors:

```
struct U {
    U(int) {}
    U(int&&) {}
};

U foo(int a = 0) { return a; }

int main() { foo(); }
```

In C++17 mode the program is accepted by all compilers, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b8hhEh948

However in C++20 mode, GCC rejects it with the error:

```
In function 'U foo(int)':
<source>:6:27: error: conversion from 'int' to 'U' is ambiguous
    6 | U foo(int a = 0) { return a; }
      |                           ^
<source>:3:5: note: candidate: 'U::U(int&&)'
    3 |     U(int&&) {}
      |     ^
<source>:2:5: note: candidate: 'U::U(int)'
    2 |     U(int) {}
      |     ^
```

demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fMvEPMGhq

I think this is because of C++20 feature [P1825R0: Merged wording for P0527R1 and P1155R3 (more implicit moves)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1825r0.html)
And the function `foo` according to this feature must be equivalent to

```
U foo(int a = 0) { return std::move(a); }
```

which is rejected due to constructor selection ambiguity by all compilers, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TjWeP965q

Is GCC the only right compiler in above example in C++20 mode?

Comment: I would say the main issue here is that this type makes no sense - `U u = 42;` is ill-formed. And after that, I don't think it matters too much. I think gcc is wrong to reject this tho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens here is that the way that gcc went about implementing P1825.

In this example:

```cpp
U foo(int a) {
    return a;
}
```

The C++17 and C++20 language rules (no change here) are that we first treat `a` as an rvalue and if that overload resolution fails (in C++17, it was also required to bind to `int&&`), then we treat `a` as an lvalue. With that rule, this code works - the overload resolution with `a` as an xvalue fails due to ambiguity (because `U` is a silly type), so we fallback to treating `a` as an lvalue, and that succeeds.

But gcc's implementation doesn't do that. Instead it treats `a` as an xvalue that can also bind to non-const lvalue references, and performs a single round of overload resolution (it does so in an effort to avoid breaking some code, see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91427#c2)). That single round of overload resolution is ambiguous, because simply treating `a` as an xvalue is ambiguous and there's no lvalue ref constructor that is relevant here, so gcc rejects the example.

But in this case, I'd say this is `U`'s fault rather than gcc's. If `U` either (a) had two constructors that took `int const&` and `int&&` as is usual or (b) had a single constructor that took an `int`, the example would compile fine. Note that in the (b) case, the C++17 rule would perform a copy but the C++20 rule would perform a move (since we no longer require that the constructor specifically takes an rvalue reference).

Comment: [P2266](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2021/p2266r1.html) is supposed to make `a` simply an xvalue, so that it’s ambiguous but doesn’t support a `int&` constructor at all.